# Show that a sequence is not a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Set $$ a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n}$$ for each $n\in \mathbb N.$ Show that $\{a_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence even though $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n) =0$$ (Therefore $\{a_n\}$ does not have a limit).

I am really confused on Cauchy sequences but as I tried working through this problem, I think my sequence can be stated as $a_n= 1/n$. So if I use $|a_{n+1}−a_n|$ I get $\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$ which goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. And since $1/n$ also goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, shouldn't that mean that the sequence converges and is a cauchy sequence?

 Sorry for my typing, I am still unsure of how to format my questions properly on here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: Hint: For any $n > 0$, $|a_{2n} - a_n| > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: See the text of my edit for how to use Mathjax to write math on here. Also, images are frowned upon unless necessary, will edit that too.

Comment: Also: "I think my sequence can be stated as $a_n=\frac{1}{n}.$" No. The problem states what $a_n$ is and it is not that. It is $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots +\frac{1}{n}.$ Thus you have $a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{1}{n+1},$ which does go to zero. The point of the question is that this does not imply that $a_n$ converges. Daniel Schepler's hint will help you see the sequence is not Cauchy (or equivalently that it is not convergent.)

Comment: "I think my sequence can be stated as an=1/n."  No.  Read it again.  It specifically states that $a_n = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + ..... + \frac 1n$.  This is *NOT* $a_n = \frac 1n$.

Comment: "So if I use |an+1−an| I get 1n+1−1n which goes to 0 as n goes to infinity. "  That's not what you have to show.  You have to show that $|a_m - a_n| \to 0$ for all $m,n \ge N$.  It doesn't matter if $|a_{n} - a_{n+1}|\to 0$ if $|a_{m} - a_n| \not \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In simply terms: A cauchy sequence is one in which after a certain $N$ then *ALL* possible pairs are close together.

This is a sequence where only pairs of immediately consecutive pairs are close together.

So $|a_n - a_{n+1}|$ might be less than $\epsilon$ and $|a_m - a_{m+1}|$ might be less than $\epsilon$.  But $|a_n - a_m|$ might be over a hundred million.

For instance.  Take $a_{21} - a_{20}$ that is $\frac 1 {21}$.  That's pretty small.  But take $a_{40} - a_{20}$ that is $\frac 1{40} + \frac 1{39} + .... + \frac 1{21}$ that is, relatively speaking, pretty large.

We *can* say, for $\epsilon = \frac 1{20}$ if $n \ge 20$ then $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < \epsilon$.  But we can *NOT* say if $n,m \ge 20$ then $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$, because that simply is not true as $m = 40; n = 20$ shows.  And it is the LATTER that is the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

In fact consider $a_{1024} - a_{32} = \frac 1{1024} + \frac 1{1023} + ..... + \frac 1{513} + \frac 1{512} + \frac 1 {511}+ ..... + \frac 1{257} + \frac 1{256} + \frac 1{255} + ...... + \frac 1{129}+ \frac 1{128} + \frac 1{127} + .... + \frac 1{65} + \frac 1{64} + \frac 1{63} +.... + \frac 1{33}$

$> \frac 1{1024} + \frac 1{1024} + ..... + \frac 1{1024} + \frac 1{512} + \frac 1{512}+..... + \frac 1{512} + \frac 1{256} + \frac 1{256} + ...... + \frac 1{256}+ \frac 1{128} + \frac 1{128} + .... + \frac 1{128} + \frac 1{64} + \frac 1{64} +.... + \frac 1{34}$

$= 512*\frac 1{1024} + 256*\frac 1{512} + 128*\frac 1{256} + 64*\frac 1{128} + 32*\frac 1{64} = \frac 12 +\frac 12 +\frac 12 +\frac 12 +\frac 12   =2 \frac 12$.

$2\frac 12$ is pretty bigg and we can make this a *lot* bigger if we needed to.

To be cauchy *ANY* pair must be close together.  And that simply is not the case here.

Proving it is another issue and has a trick.  And I gave you a big hint to the trick.

Hint:  Prove that $a_{2^k} > \frac k2$.